# Haskell function for computing sublist of a list

Tags: haskell

Can someone explain to me what does this haskell code mean?

```
sublists [] = [[]]
sublists (x:xs) = [x:sublist | sublist <- sublists xs] ++ sublists xs
```

I know this function computes sublist of a given list. But , I want to know how it works.

Comment: Have you considered learning Haskell?

Comment: Do you not understand the algorithm, or the Haskell implementation of the algorithm?

Comment: The interesting part is why it performs the recursive call twice instead of calculating it once and using the result twice. That's actually very important. Can you figure out why?

Answer (score 1):

```
sublists :: [a] -> [[a]]
sublists [] = [[]]
sublists (x:xs) = [x:sublist | sublist <- sublists xs] ++ sublists xs

--  ghci> sublists [1,2,3] 
--  [[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]

--    (each sublist l1 in (sublists [2 , 3])
--      
--      (1 : l1)) 
--        concat (sublists [2, 3])
--
--       sublists [2, 3] = 
--         (each sublist l2 in (sublists [3])
--           (2 : l2)) 
--             concat (sublists [3]) 
--
--             sublists [3] = 
--                 (3 : []) concat [[]]
--                 = [[3], []]
--    
--    now substituting back into the recursion
--        [[2, 3], [2], [3], []]
--    
--    [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1], [2, 3], [2], [3], []]
```